# post functional test failing

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I am trying to create a functional test that tests the create method in one of my controllers. For the life of me, I cannot figure out why this is failing. I am getting one failure, and zero errors:

```
1) Failure:
test_should_create_order(OrdersControllerTest) [/Users/user/rails_work/depot/test/functional/orders_controller_test.rb:38]:
"Order.count" didn't change by 1.
<3> expected but was
<2>.
```

So, Im pretty sure this means that my functionals test was unable to make an Order. Here is my test:

```
  setup do
    @order = orders(:one)
  end

  test "should create order" do
    assert_difference('Order.count') do
      post :create, order: @order.attributes.slice(Order.accessible_attributes)
    end

    assert_redirected_to store_url
  end
```

my orders fixture:

```
one:
  name: Dave Thomas
  address: MyText
  email: dave@example.org
  pay_type: Check
```

and my Order#create controller:

```
def create
    @order = Order.new(params[:order])
    @order.add_line_items_from_cart(current_cart)

    respond_to do |format|
      if @order.save
        Cart.destroy(session[:cart_id])
        session[:cart_id] = nil 
        format.html { redirect_to store_url, notice: 'Thank you for your order' }
        format.json { render json: @order, status: :created, location: @order }
      else
        @cart = current_cart
        format.html { render action: "new" }
        format.json { render json: @order.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end
```

Now, if I change the setup method in my functional test to:

```
@order = Order.create(orders(:one))
```

Instead of:

```
@order = orders(:one)
```

The failure disappears, but I get about 8 of these errors:

```
NoMethodError: undefined method `stringify_keys' for #<Order:0x007f8c62dbb960>
```

If anyone can help me fix this functional test, I would more than appreciate it. Any and all input is welcome.

Comment: Maybe your authorization fails and order isn't being created during your POST?

Comment: How would I check on the autorization? I have googled it, but I cannot find it.

Comment: Have you made some `before_filter` to check if the user is logged in? Maybe your `create` action isn't invoked at all?

Comment: I had the same problem, but with Rails 4. Turns out that pay_type in my fixture was `check` instead of `Check`. Yours is right, but can you verify that your other fixtures are correct?

Answer (score 0):

**Bottom line:** assign each `order` attribute individually.

I'm not familiar with the 'mass assignment' vulnerability (new to Rails), but [here (Pragmatic Forums)](http://forums.pragprog.com/forums/148/topics/10843) is a case of someone having difficulty with that specific test because of it.

Try spelling out each attribute of the order individually. Instead of

```
post :create, order: @order.attributes.slice(Order.accessible_attributes)
```

use

```
post :create, order: { 
    address: @order.address,
    email: @order.email,
    name: @order.name,
    pay_type: @order.pay_type
}
```

The test as a whole will be this:

```
test "should create order" do
    assert_difference('Order.count') do
        post :create, order: { address: @order.address, email: @order.email, name: @order.name, pay_type: @order.pay_type }
    end

    assert_redirected_to store_path
end
```